# EC2 Instance Metadata - Filter Private IPs based on Mac or Interface Index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am writing a shell script that will run in an EC2 instance with 2 interfaces (Mgmt and Service NICs). The need to be able to grab the IP of the secondary interface (index1) via the metadata; however, I am only able to do it by filtering the mac address. The problem is that the mac addresses are never in the same order, so depending on the exact order of the Mac addresses, it may return the IP of the primary interface (Index0). Here is how I am doing my filter

```
curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/ > macs
MAC=$(awk '{if(NR==2) print $0}' macs ) 
SMNET_IP=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta- 
data/network/interfaces/macs/$MAC/local-ipv4s)
echo {$SMNET_IP}
```

How can I query both interfaces private IP addresses via the metadata based on either the interface index or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can query each network interface's device number, using the `device-number` fragment under the MAC.  From there, it's just a matter of getting the IP address for the first network interface, the one with a number of 0.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

URL_BASE="http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs"

for MAC in $(curl -s ${URL_BASE}/); do
    if [[ "$(curl -s ${URL_BASE}/${MAC}device-number)" == "0" ]]; then
        LOCAL_IP=$(curl -s ${URL_BASE}/${MAC}local-ipv4s)
        echo "Found device 0 with MAC: ${MAC}, IP of ${LOCAL_IP}"
    fi
done
```